# Find an autonomous differential equation with a given phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My DE course uses an online homework service to distribute and collect homework. One of the problems in this set is to furnish an autonomous DE consistent with the phase portrait below:

[image]

I came up with $y' = (y-1)^2(y-3)^2(y-5)^2$, which the program rejected. Have I made a mistake, or has the program?

**Edit**: Another problem was to find an autonomous DE consistent with the phase portrait

[image]

For this, I came up with $(y-1)(y-3)^2(y-5)$. I expanded this into $y^4 - 12y^3 + 50y^2 - 84y + 45$ and got marked correct. When I expanded $(y-1)^2(y-3)^2(y-5)^2$ into $225-690 y +799 y^2 - 444 y^3+127$ $ y^4 -18 y^5 +y^6$ using Walpha, I got marked wrong.

Is there some error I'm making? (And do problems like this actually arise in "real life"?!)

Comment: Are the tickmarks at $1$, $3$ and $5$ supposed to imply that those are equilibrium points, or are they just 
the scale on the axis?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I was assuming they were the zeroes of $f(y)$ in $y' = f(y)$. (Maybe *that's* it?)

Comment: @Robert-israel:these are clearly equilibrium points but how find out these are sink points or source points

Comment: What sort of information does the program require as input? In particular, are you supposed to set any information about the points 1,3,5, and if so, what options are you allowed to tick off for them? Is there any particular reason the case $y>5$ is cut off?

Comment: @anon None whatsoever. (I'll spare you a screen cap....)

Comment: However, I was assuming that $1, 3$, and $5$ were zeroes of the $f(y)$ with $y' = f(y)$.

Comment: Even if 1,3 and 5 are equilibria, still you have no information on what's going on beyond 5. Try $(y-1)^2(y-3)^2(y-5)$.

Comment: @tst I'll try $-(y-1)^2(y-3)^2(y-5)$ (the other one doesn't have the needed properties), but honestly I think I'll wait until I can grab the instructor. I don't know how many "chances" I get here....

Comment: For your second problem, $(y-1)^2(y-3)^2(y-5)^2$ is certainly wrong because it would be $\ge 0$ everywhere, contradicting the downward arrows.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm confused by your comment. For the second problem, I submitted $(y-1)(y-3)^2(y-5)$, which was marked correct. In the first problem, all of the arrows *were* upward, so the function should be positive except at its roots, which I achieved with $(y-1)^2(y-3)^2(y-5)^2$.

Comment: Certainly a pervasive real-world problem is to get a computer system to accept a response. :) For the first graph, the factor for $y=5$ could be $(y-5)^2$, $(y-5)^4$, $(5-y)$, $\sqrt{5-y}$, $-\arctan(y-5)$, etc., assuming $y>5$ does not matter -- one wonders how robust the system is. (In my mind, the HW question is not a problem, but an exercise, the significance being that an exercise trains you on important basic concepts or skills needed to understand and solve problems. The phase portrait is an important concept as is its connection to the sign of $y'$.)

Comment: @user1296727: so what were the results for these two problems?

Comment: @Amzoti You know what? It turned out that $(y-1)^2(y-3)^2$ was accepted as a solution. I could've flipping *sworn* I'd already tried that one before asking on MSE. (Maybe I really did....) Anyway, it all worked out. :)

Comment: @user1296727: that makes sense, you had two equilibrium points and the flows are going away from them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the error in the first case was in thinking that $5$ should be a critical point; in fact, it's just a tickmark. If the tickmarks are not required to be critical points, $y'=1$ should be as acceptable as $y'=(y-1)^2(y-3)^2$.

In the second case, $y'$ has to change sign around $y=1$ and $y=5$. The ODE $y'=(y-1)(y-5)$ matches the sign pattern. So does $y'=(y-1)(y-5)(y-3)^2$, but again, having a critical point at $3$ should not be a requirement.