# Construct differential equation given the phase portrait (non-linear pendulum)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes, chaos-theory

I am curious to know how to recover the differential equation that goes with a phase portrait.  I have seen the following posts but the [first one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/293307/23593) was a $y'$ (and easy enough to "do in my head") and the [second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153398/23593) lacks the figure.

As an example, I solved (in *Mathematica*) the non-linear pendulum equation and plotted the phase portrait as below:

$$y''(t)+\frac{y'(t)}{q}+\sin \left(y(t)\right)=g \cos (\omega t)$$

Where $q$ is damping, $g$ is the forcing term while $\omega$ is the frequency of forcing.  The phase portrait ($y'$ vs $y$) is plotted:

[image]

So, now if I were given this phase portrait, **how do I derive the autonomous differential equation for it?**  I ask because I do not know the "language" to search for online.

The reason I posted this question here instead of mathematica.SE is because this is more of a Mathematics question and not so much a *Mathematica* question.

My *Mathematica* code, in case interested:

```
g = 1/10; q = 8; \[Omega] = -0.04; TMax = 40;
pSolNL = NDSolveValue[{y''[t] + (1/q) y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 
    g  Cos[\[Omega]  t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, TMax}];

ParametricPlot[{pSolNL[\[Tau]] /. \[Tau] -> t, 
  D[pSolNL[\[Tau]], \[Tau]] /. \[Tau] -> t}, {t, 0, TMax}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"y(t)", "y'(t)"}]
```

Comment: The system that produced this portrait is nonautonomous, so it's hard to see how to derive an autonomous equation for it.  The phase portrait involves a loss of information (time is implicit).  You'd be better off fitting y[t] and y'[t] rather than y'[y].  That said, check this out: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/324/5923/81.abstract

Answer (score 2):

There is no autonomous differential equation **on the plane** with this phase portrait. Notice that at some points you would need to have at least two tangents to the curve, which is impossible in autonomous systems.

Comment: So there is no way I can "reverse engineer" the pendulum equation from this?

Comment: Never from a single trajectory. But you could try to find the equation by adding $t'=1$ and thus rediscovering yours plus $t'=1$, provided that you had many trajectories and looked at the phase portrait as if the curve evolved also along a third direction (according to $t'=1$). Tortuous, and difficult to be rigorous, never seen it really, but feasible in theory. :-)

Comment: Converse to my question, is there a way I can change my pendulum differential equation towards a certain phase portrait (without a manual parametric study)? For example, I would like to decrease the number of spirals.  Clearly, I would need to find a balance between the damping and frequency and forcing.  What kind of stability analysis would I be performing?

Comment: In principle, you should increase $q$ and decrease $g$, but you surely know that already. Other than this, I would plot many other solutions. Really, to do something like you are asking for a nonautonomous equation is very much equation dependent (and for the same reason parameter dependent).